# LXD API not creating profile

Tags: curl, lxc, lxd

I am trying to create a new profile for LXC.

I did this;

```
root@nagri:/home/nagri# curl -s -k --cert ~/.config/lxc/client.crt --key ~/.config/lxc/client.key -X POST -d '{
    "name": "testing",
    "description": "Some description string",
    "config": {
        "limits.memory": "2GB"
    },
    "devices": {
        "kvm": {
            "type": "unix-char",
            "path": "/dev/kvm"
        }
    }
}' https://localhost:8443/1.0/profiles/testing | jq .
{
  "type": "sync",
  "status": "Success",
  "status_code": 200,
  "metadata": null
}
```

The output is success but no `profile` actually gets created.

```
root@nagri:/home/nagri# curl -s --unix-socket /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket a/1.0/profiles -X GET | jq
{
  "type": "sync",
  "status": "Success",
  "status_code": 200,
  "metadata": [
    "/1.0/profiles/docker",
    "/1.0/profiles/lxd-nginx"
  ]
}
```

The logs doesnt show any error or warnings either.
**/var/log/lxd/lxd.log**

```
t=2016-09-07T16:22:18+0530 lvl=info msg=handling ip=127.0.0.1:49796 method=POST url=/1.0/profiles/testing
```

What sins have I committed? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stupid stupid person. Read the [docs](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/rest-api.md) properly.

Apparently with **POST** all you can do is change the name of a profile. 
To Update a profile you'll have to use **PUT**.

first create an empty profile named `testing` by

```
$ lxc profile create testing
```

This will create an empty profile testing.

The go ahead and do this;

```
$ curl -s -k --cert ~/.config/lxc/client.crt --key ~/.config/lxc/client.key -X PUT -d '{
"name": "testing",
"description": "Some description string",
"config": {
    "limits.memory": "2GB"
},
"devices": {
    "kvm": {
        "type": "unix-char",
        "path": "/dev/kvm"
    }
}
  }' https://localhost:8443/1.0/profiles/testing | jq .
```

This will update your profile.

Enjoy.